# Could we please have election data added to the API?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, elections

It would be great if the election data were available from the API.

Use cases:

- Applications can display notifications when certain events happen in the election.
- A user might want to check their standings in the primaries or something using their mobile phone.
- Statistics can be gathered.

Comment: Yay! Looks like it's a planned feature now.

Comment: Any update on this? People keep pulling the data out of the election pages which—of course—is somewhat inefficient. So some API to get some basic data would be really useful.